# Why is the Cauchy Schwarz inequality a special case of Holder's inequality?

Tags: cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

[image: Holder's inequality] --- $(1)$

[image: Cauchy Schwarz inequality] --- $(2)$

Cauchy Schwarz inequality is said to be a special case of Holder's inequality when $p=2,q=2$.
$(1)$ is the Holder's inequality and $(2)$ is the Cauchy Schwarz inequality.
I cannot see how putting $p=2$ and $q=2$ in $(1)$ yields $(2)$.
i.e. saying $|a+b|≤c$ isn't the same as saying $|a|+|b|≤c$.

Comment: I don't follow what the question is exactly. Can you explain a bit better?

Comment: You have a low resolution image of the inequalities that you are interested in, one of which is labeled "Hölder's inequality," and the other is labeled "Hölder's sum inequality."  The second looks like Cauchy-Schwarz to me, which looks like a direct application of the first inequality (after squaring both sides).  I don't understand your question...

Comment: @XanderHenderson no it isn't. It says a special case of Holder's sum inequality. Which is Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I edited it. Could you check it once more?

Comment: @user21820 maybe because I don't know how to do it efficiently from the mobile app? And are the equations completely unintelligible? I can understand them fine.

Comment: Well I did not downvote your question, but your use of images instead of LaTeX might have been one reason of the downvoters'. The site instruction explicitly tells askers to use LaTeX, so...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for replying to an old question, but I'm reading a book where this is mentioned, and I wasn't satisfied with the other answers.

As Quoka mentions, Hölder's inequality with $p = q = 2$ yields
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n \left|a_k b_k\right| \leq \left(\sum_{k = 1}^n \left|a_k\right|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(\sum_{k = 1}^n \left|b_k\right|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

However, to obtain the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality (apparently weaker), a lower bound must be created:
$$
\left|\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k b_k\right| \leq \sum_{k = 1}^n \left|a_k b_k\right|
$$

This should be easy to prove, knowing that $\left|a + b\right| \leq \left|a\right| + \left|b\right|$.

It is then safe to square both sides:
$$
\left|\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k b_k\right|^2 \leq \left(\sum_{k = 1}^n \left|a_k\right|^2\right) \left(\sum_{k = 1}^n \left|b_k\right|^2\right)
$$

So, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can be seen as a special case of Hölder's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Pugging $p=q=2$ into Holder's inequality you obtain
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\lvert a_kb_k\rvert \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lvert a_k\rvert^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lvert b_k\rvert^2\right)^{1/2}
$$
Squaring either side you obtain exactly Cauchy's inequality;
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lvert a_kb_k\rvert\right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lvert a_k\rvert^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lvert b_k\rvert^2\right)
$$

Comment: But Cauchy Schwarz inequality doesn't involve absolute values within the summation?

Comment: @HritRoy Sure it does.  However, if the $a_k$ and $b_k$ are real, then $|a_k|^2 = a_k^2$, so they are often elided in real spaces.

Comment: @XanderHenderson see the 2nd image which you yourself called the Cauchy Schwarz inequality. I don't see any modulus sign on the left hand side of the inequality. When I take the square root, the modulus sign will be outside the entire sum.