# How is Hölder's inequality with $p=q=2$ equivalent to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says that

$$\left|\sum_i x_i y_i \right| \leq \sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_i y_i^2}$$

Hölder's inequality for the special case $p=q=2$ says that

$$\sum_i |x_i y_i| \leq \sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_i y_i^2}$$

Clearly the former implies the latter via the triangle inequality. However, there appears to be general consensus online that the latter also implies the former. For example, [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HoeldersInequalities.html)

> [Hölder's inequality with] $p=q=2$ becomes Cauchy's inequality

or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality)

> The special case [of Hölder's inequality with] p = q = 2 gives a form of the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

Why is this true? It seems to me that Cauchy's inequality is a stronger statement than this special case of Hölder's inequality, and so Hölder's inequality does not become Cauchy's inequality at all.

This has been asked before here [Why is the Cauchy Schwarz inequality a special case of Holder's inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650612/why-is-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-a-special-case-of-holders-inequality) but not answered. In particular, Hrit Roy's final comment on the answer is not dealt with.

Comment: Hölder+Triangle gives the CS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Clearly the former implies the latter via the triangle inequality." No, it is actually the other way around. The triangle inequality states
$$|\sum_i x_iy_i| \leq \sum_i |x_i y_i|,$$

so clearly Hölders inequality implies Cauchy-Schwarz and it would seem that Hölders is the stronger statement, although they are equivalent. To see that Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies this special case of Hölders inequality, apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the vectors $(|x_1|,...,|x_n|)$ and $(|y_1|,...,|y_n|)$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Holder’s inequality for $p=q=2$ is stronger than CS inequality.

Triangle inequality:

$\left|\sum{x_{i}y_{i}}\right|\leq\sum{\left|{x_{i}y{i}}\right|}$

Therefore:

$\left|\sum{x_{i}y_{i}}\right|\leq\sum{\left|{x_{i}y{i}}\right|}\leq\sqrt{\sum{x_{i}^{2}}}\sqrt{\sum{y_{i}^{2}}}$