# Proving the "triangle inequality": $|\sum_i x_iy_i| \leq \sum_i |x_i y_i|$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This is regarding the responses to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556105/how-is-h%C3%B6lders-inequality-with-p-q-2-equivalent-to-cauchy-schwarz-inequality?noredirect=1&lq=1).

In the responses, it is claimed that there is a "triangle inequality" that states that

> $$|\sum_i x_iy_i| \leq \sum_i |x_i y_i|,$$

This is certainly no version of triangle inequality I am familiar with. I am, however, aware of a related theorem:

$|\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y}| \le |\mathbf{x}| \cdot |\mathbf{y}|\tag{1}$

where $|\mathbf{x}| = \left(\sum_1^k x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$.

Is it possible to obtain the "triangle inequality" from $(1)$? Is it that $|\mathbf{x}| \cdot |\mathbf{y}| = \sum_i |x_i y_i|$, somehow?

Where is this "triangle inequality" even coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With $z_i:=x_iy_i$, this is a special case of the usual triangle inequality $|\sum_iz_i|\le\sum_i|z_i|$, which we can prove by induction once we verify the $2$-term case $|z+w|\le|z|+|w|$. In particular,$$(|z|+|w|)^2-|z+w|^2=2(|z||w|-\color{blue}{\Re(zw^\ast)})\ge0$$(for real values, the blue term reduces to $zw$).